# How to get sensors data of Mobile phone

Tags: android, ubuntu, mobile, gps, android-sensors

I have installed Ubuntu on my android phone, now i want to get data of sensors of my phone (e.g GPS, IMU etc).How can i get that data after installing Ubuntu on it.

An kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain somehow the device drivers for the sensor, or write them yourself, which seems a bit too difficult to do.

Install back Android and you'll have all access to the sensors.